# What are the implications of deterministic chaos: useful or detrimental?

Tags: biology, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems, complex-systems, models

I am new to the concept of chaos theory and as a layman I am struggling to understand what is the significance and implication of chaos in ecological systems such as the [chaotic predator prey model](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Predator-prey_model). I have understood how to know that a system is chaotic but I do not yet understood why it is advantageous or if it is problematic in terms of biological/ecological models. I have read several papers the important ones being "[Chaos in low-dimensional Lotka–Volterra models of competition](https://doi.org/10.1088/0951-7715/19/10/006)" and "[Bifurcations and chaotic dynamics in a 4-dimensional competitive Lotka–Volterra system](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11071-009-9547-3)". But I failed to capture what happens when such ecological systems become chaotic-- does it mean death of a species or stability. In this regard I would be grateful if somebody could help in clarifying these doubts and confusions with an intuitive answer:

1. Is chaos a special kind of stable, equilibrium state?
2. What is the implication of appearance of chaos and disappearance of chaos in such ecological models?

Comment: I fail to see how your question pertains to physics, specifically. It seems to be more of a question about mathematics, mathematical modeling,  and biolody/ecology.

Comment: Related: [Is instability + sensitivity to initial conditions = Chaos?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/535773/75633).

Comment: @BioPhysicist That's actually a typical problem in the traditional field of Nonlinear dynamics and chaos of Physics. It's, for instance, the 2nd item in the list of topics in the scope of the journal [Physical Review E](https://journals.aps.org/pre/about).

Comment: This question had been migrated to Mathematics SE and quickly bounced back from there. See discussion [in their meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33481/418568).

Comment: @stafusa I am not saying nonlinear dynamics and chaos are not relevant to physics. I am saying this specific question is not asking a physics question. I always give the example of solving quadratic equations. Should we allow questions of the form "How do I solve this for x: $5x^2-2x+3=0$?" just because in physics one might need to solve the equation $\frac12at^2+v_0t+x_0=0$ for constant acceleration motion? Furthermore, this question is specifically asking about these concepts in the context of biological/ecological models. Not all physics-adjacent questions are on topic for PSE.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I understand what you mean, but you're failing to consider that in the field of ND&Chaos we often study the dynamics of a system regardless of its application (economy, biology, circuits, etc.) -- and we do so as physicists, without the formal rigor usually demanded for a mathematics research. There are many examples of publications about Lotka–Volterra in physics journals ([e.g.](https://doi.org/10.1143/PTP.71.930)). Here, they ask what happens to the ecological system, worry about the presence of noise (in the comments), etc.; they ask if a species will die out, not if $x\to0$.

Comment: Actually, the [journal](https://www.springer.com/journal/11071) of one of the papers mentioned in the OP even describes itself as (my emphasis) "An International Journal of Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos **in Engineering Systems**", but they published a paper on a biological system. The area of ND&Chaos qualifies as physics less by its subject matter than by its methods, which mingle mathematical results with numerical simulations with the art of making estimates and how to best mathematically model a phenomenon - that is, the art of making "physical arguments", but extended to all of science.

Comment: @stafusa I completely agree with everything in your previous two comments. You are still reading my point as "this topic is not relevant to physics", which is not what I am saying.

Comment: @BioPhysicist OK. Well, in Math SE the question also [was closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4112920/418568), so maybe it's indeed flawed and will remain closed on both sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Is chaos a special kind of stable, equilibrium state?

If the system has a chaotic attractor, then chaos in this system is *dynamically* stable, which means this behavior will persist against small perturbations. Beware though - in some, especially old texts, chaotic behavior is called "unstable" for being irregular.

> what happens when such ecological systems become chaotic - does it mean death of a species or stability?

In a population dynamics model the death/extinction of a species $x$ simply means that from then on $x=\text{const.}=0$, which is a regular [steady state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady_state), not a chaotic one.

> 2. What is the implication of appearance of chaos and disappearance of chaos in such ecological models?

A system (biological or not) being chaotic only means that its behavior is irregular and exponentially sensitive to small changes.

The biological consequences of such behavior are model specific. For instance, one could conjecture that, by being irregular, the size of the population might be out of sync with the seasons - which could be detrimental for the species if a large population arises in a low-resource period.

More concretely, [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1038/s42003-019-0715-9) mentions:

> a range of more specific possible biological functions for chaos have since been proposed, including potentially maximizing the information processing capacity of both neural systems and gene regulatory networks, enabling multistable perception, allowing neural systems to flexibly transition between different activity patterns, and boosting cellular survival rates through the promotion of heterogeneous gene expression. [...]
> a model of white blood cell concentrations in chronic granulocytic leukemia can display varying levels of chaos, and knowing how chaotic those concentrations are in actual leukemia patients could have important implications for health outcomes. As another example, models of the human cortex predict that macro-scale cortical electrodynamics should be weakly chaotic during waking states and should be strongly chaotic under propofol anesthesia; if this prediction is true, then detecting changing levels of chaos in large-scale brain activity could be useful for monitoring depth of anesthesia and for basic anesthesia research.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain a bit more on whether stability = chaos for deterministic dyn. system or whether steady = chaos or whether stability and steady state is the same term and how it relates to chaos phenomenon. Lastly, you mentioned that an ecological system if chaotic means that the behaviour is irregular -- what does this imply? Does it mean that irregularity/chaos all species will survive?

Comment: @Sm1 _dynamically stable_ = the behavior (chaotic or not) persists in face of, e.g., noise added to the system, i.e., it's robust; _steady_ = any transient behavior is over and the system reached its final state, for instance, its attractor (chaotic or not). So, you see, _chaos_ and these two terms are independent. In the answer I added some links to definitions that should help. And an _irregular_ behavior is not periodic, so at least one population survives and oscillates unpredictably - probably other populations do so too, but it's possible one or more of the others went extinct.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. However, you mentioned about the effect of noise in your comment. If noise suppresses deterministic chaos at high levels of noise, then for an ecological model such as the chaotic predator prey it would no longer be chaotic. So what is the implication then? How to interpret the influence of noise (presence and absence) for such chaotic systems? Could you please briefly explain this part based on your comment?

Comment: @Sm1 I should probably have said "perturbation", noise is indeed more complicated. If you do have noise, what happens depends on the details of the system and on the noise, and chaos can be suppressed, but not necessarily is (though, as you say, the system is of course no longer deterministic). A main effect of noise can be to break barriers and make boundaries diffuse in phase space.

Answer (score 1):

When considering the consequences of chaos on real systems, you first needs to consider to what you are comparing it and what your scientific context is. There are two important contexts:

#### Understanding given real dynamics

In this context, the most interesting alternative to chaos is not a regular dynamics (fixed point or periodic) but a stochastic one.

The dynamics of most ecological systems falls into one of the following categories:

- Convergence to an equilibrium, be it with all populations surviving¹ or not.
- Regular oscillations in response to an external driver, e.g., seasons.
- Irregular oscillations, i.e., with no clear frequency. A big open question is whether these oscillations are primarily chaotic (i.e., deterministic) or just noise (stochastic), where the latter can be just noisy oscillations around an equilibrium or periodic dynamics made irregular by noise. Of course the answer could depend on the system, but so far there are only a few disputed claims for a few systems.

The first two cases are generally well understood and clearly not chaotic. In the latter case, the question can be rephrased as: Is the dynamics is primarily deterministic? If the answer is *yes,* we can model, predict, and control the dynamics to some extent; otherwise we mostly cannot. The answer may also help to predict how the dynamics behaves in response to parameter changes (e.g., climate change): A chaotic oscillation can suddenly transition to some other kind of dynamics, a stochastic system is less likely to do that (though there are such phenomena like stochastic resonance).

¹ Which is called *stable* in ecology. Mind that in the context of dynamical systems *stable* means something different, e.g., the extinction of all populations is a stable in the dynamical sense.

#### Understanding the effect of parameter changes on a model

A common type of study investigates the impact of a control parameter (e.g., temperature, nutrient influx, pH) on the dynamics of a model system, usually a deterministic one.
Typically, the dynamics changes between an equilibrium, periodic and chaotic one in bifurcations and other sudden transitions.

The most important transitions in this context are the ones where the abundance of some population drastically in- or decreases (tipping points) or oscillations arise, be they periodic or chaotic. As far as I can tell, transitions between chaos and regular oscillations (of comparable amplitude) are not of that big interest. There may be exceptions though, e.g., if the system in question drives another system. There are some speculations that chaos may act as an ecologically stabilising factor, but so may regular oscillations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain a bit more on whether stability = chaos for deterministic dyn. system or whether steady = chaos or whether stability and steady state is the same term and how it relates to chaos phenomenon. Lastly, you mentioned that an ecological system if chaotic means that the behaviour is irregular -- what does this imply? Does it mean that irregularity/chaos all species will survive?